# compile a matlab gui for win 32 system using 64 bit win and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compilation, 32bit-64bit, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I want to compile a matlab GUI as an `exe`, I'm using MATLAB 2012 and have win 64 bit. The compiled program can't be ececuted on win 32 afterwards. I couldn't find any option when using 'deploytool' to make the program work on PCs which have win 32 as well.

I would appreciate any comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot actually use 64 bit matlab to build a 32 bit program.

When I faced the same situation, Mathworks recommended me to (also) install 32 bit matlab  on my 64 bit windows. I did not try it, but that should allow you to build 32 bit programs again.

Comment: Thanks! I will install MATLAB 32 bit then.